# cloverage FileNotFoundException

Tags: clojure, code-coverage, speclj

I would like to use cloverage so I can check how much of my code base is tested by speclj. However after installing cloverage as a lein plugin and running: `lein cloverage` I see the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
Could not locate app/unit/core_spec__init.class or app/unit/core_spec.clj on classpath.
Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.,
compiling:(/private/var/folders/w_/yt926bqs21g44f257yz05ctsjbv948/T/form-init4597524674545750330.clj:1:125)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate app/component/core_spec__init.class or app/component/core_spec.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.
```

I've not used cloverage before so what to check if I'm using it correctly, has anyone come across this issue before?

This is what my project.clj looks like:

```
(defproject app version
  :dependencies [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.5"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]
                 [org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 "1.7.25"]
                 [log4j/log4j "1.2.17" :exclusions [javax.mail/mail
                                                    javax.jms/jms
                                                    com.sun.jmdk/jmxtools
                                                    com.sun.jmx/jmxri]]
                 [metosin/compojure-api "1.1.11"]
                 [metosin/ring-swagger "0.24.3"]
                 [compojure "1.6.0"]
                 [cheshire "5.8.0"]
                 [ring "1.6.3"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [ring-logger "0.7.7"]
                 [environ "1.1.0"]
                 [korma "0.4.3"]
                 [blackwater "0.0.9"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.1.7"]
                 [siili/humanize "0.1.1"]
                 [amazonica "0.3.117"]
                 ]

  :main app.cli.core
  :plugins [
            [lein-ring "0.12.1"]
            [lein-cloverage "1.0.10"]
            [speclj "3.3.2"]
            ]

  :test-paths ["spec"]

  :profiles {
             :uberjar {:aot :all}

             :user    {
                       :plugins
                       [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.16.0"]
                              [lein-kibit "0.1.6"]
                              [nightlight/lein-nightlight "1.0.0"]
                              [lein-cloverage "1.0.6"]
                              [jonase/eastwood "0.2.3"]
                              [lein-cloverage "1.0.9"]
                        [speclj "3.3.2"]]
                       }

             :dev     {
                       :dependencies [
                                      [ring-mock "0.1.3"]
                                      [clj-http "3.7.0"]
                                      [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                                      [speclj "3.3.2"]
                                      [clj-time "0.14.2"]
                                      [listora/again "0.1.0"]
                                      [environ "1.1.0"]
                                      ]
                       }
             }
  )
```

spec/app/component/core_spec.clj

```
(ns app.component.core_spec
  (:require [speclj.core :refer :all]
            [clojure.data.json :as json]
            [clj-http.client :as client]
            [clj-time.core :as t]
            [again.core :as again]
            [clj-time.format :as f]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]))

    (describe "app"
        ; tests and things...
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably unrelated to Cloverage specifically. It looks like you're trying to `require` `app.unit.core-spec`, and that file either doesn't exist or hasn't been properly named (don't forget source files should have underscores, not dashes!)

Comment: The file does exists with that namespace and im using underscores.

Comment: What is the filename and full file path relative to your `project.clj`?

Comment: The namespace is app.unit.core-spec and the file path is spec/app/unit/core_spec.clj

Comment: Do you have that first `spec` folder specifically added as a `src-path` or `test-path` in your `project.clj`?

Comment: Oh also duh your filename *is* with a hyphen, not an underscore! That's the problem, as I said in my answer. You want the file to be named `core_spec.clj`, not `core-spec.clj`

Comment: oh sorry that was a typo it is actually core_spec.clj

Comment: In my ```project.clj``` I have this ```:test-paths ["spec"]```

Comment: When I run lein spec the tests run so not sure if i've just not configured something for cloverage?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you add `spec` to `src-paths` instead of `test-paths`?

Comment: The project doesnt build get this: ```No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: clojure.lang.PersistentVector```

Comment: Also, did you check for the filename on the file in `/app/component/core_spec.clj`? Looks like your stacktrace has two individual trace issues.

Comment: Oh, my spec directory structure was not correctly mirroring the src directory structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168811/discussion-between-venantius-and-freid001).